# Is 'image' rule secure enough?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

So I'm trying to create a upload profile picture for my website... And I'm wondering if the `image` rule is secure enough in Laravel.

Consider the following code:

```
input = [
    'profile_picture' => Input::file('profile_picture'),
];

$rules = ['profile_picture' => 'required|image'];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return 'It\'s not an image!';
}
```

Pretty simple, The thing I want you to focus on is the `image` rule in the `rules` array.

It seems like Laravel validates image by their MIME type. As we know, It can be edited from the client and then send to the server by using something like Tamper Data or Burp Proxy.

And you say how do you know It validates image by their MIME type? Well... Take a look at  this code below, This is the `Validator.php` class that Laravel uses for validation. It contains every rule I think. And to be specific, This is the `validateImage` function, Which is the `image` rule.

**Validator/validateImage():**

```
/**
* Validate the MIME type of a file is an image MIME type.
*
* @param  string  $attribute
* @param  mixed   $value
* @return bool
*/
protected function validateImage($attribute, $value)
{
    return $this->validateMimes($attribute, $value, array('jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'));
}
```

As the Doc-block says, It validates it by their MIME type.

So is it secure enough? Any questions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not secure. At least you can't be sure if it is a real image as the MIME type can be manipulated. What usually helps is to use `getimagesize()` which will return `false` if the file is not an image. So you could extend the validator with this rule:

```
Validator::extend('real_image', function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
    if($value instanceof Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile){
        if(getimagesize($value->getRealPath() !== false){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And add that to your validation rules:

```
$rules = ['profile_picture' => 'required|image|real_image'];
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question We can't say anything as secured or not.

But Yes **Laravel validates image only few format which you specified**. It is also mentioned [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation).

If you think it is a basic validation, then you shall use the third party package like [this](https://github.com/cviebrock/image-validator#examples) which validates image by aspect ratio (Which only a real image can have it)